# Xamarin.Android AlertDialog pops up twice inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-dialog

I'm having a problem with an AlertDialog , It appears twice,

when i click on one of the buttons it re-appears again, here is my code.

```
   var builder = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
   var view = Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog, null);
   Android.App.AlertDialog dialog = null;
   builder.SetView(view);  
   dialog = builder.Create();  
   dialog.SetButton2("CANCEL", delegate { dialog.Dismiss(); });
   dialog.Show();
```

any idea what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint on the code and see if it's really called twice? and if it's, is the call stack different?

Comment: I found the solution to this thread, when adding the event handlers to my buttons that call the method with the above code , i had to first detach the events   e.g  btShowDialog.Click -= -eventHandler ;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much. I was using an anonymous method/delegate btnOne.clicked += (o, e) => ...) , and it was still calling the fragment twice, had to change to a named delegate then followed your instructions, I first unsubscribed then I resubscribed. Thanks

I found the root cause in my application, I had a method called SetUp which has my event handlers included. I call it in the OnCreate method, and also I call the method from the OnResume method. Im a noob so learning as I go, might have been obvious to others, but its not so obvious when learning. Also remember OnResume is called after the OnPause, and since your main activity is paused because of the fragment, when you dismiss the fragment, OnResume is called and the event handlers called again